# Cannot build source in XCODE 8 iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have developed iOS application using Swift 2.3. and I have put the application to the app store in review process, apparently they have rejected it due to crash in iOS 10 .

Then in order to fix it I have downloaded the Xcode 8 and tried to build the app without converting code in to swift 3 using legacy setting

But I couldn't build the app. There was few compile errors in pods that I have used. (Alamofire framework)

error :-  and there will more

```
private func trustIsValid(trust: SecTrust) -> Bool {
        var isValid = false

        var result = SecTrustResultType(kSecTrustResultInvalid)
        let status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result)

        if status == errSecSuccess {
            let unspecified = SecTrustResultType(kSecTrustResultUnspecified)
            let proceed = SecTrustResultType(kSecTrustResultProceed)

            isValid = result == unspecified || result == proceed
        }

        return isValid
    }
```

So I did a small digging apparently Alamofire has released a new version for Xcode 8 so i have put that version, apparently I can't integrate that version in to my source code since it's in Swift 2.3.

Can someone help me to get over with this issue, problem was I can't release the app to App store since there is a crash in iOS 10 and I can't check it since I don't have iOS 10.

Comment: Either keep your code in Swift 2.3 with all dependencies in Swift 2.3 (set Alamofire to a previous version) or upgrade everything to Swift 3.0 (your code and all dependencies). It's possible that some dependencies won't have Swift 3 versions yet. It seems you want the first option, so just set Alamofire to the last version before upgrade to Swift 3 (Alamofire 3.5.0).

Comment: What's the crash?

Comment: I had to set the "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" to Yes on some of the pods I use, like Alamofire and AlamofireImage in order to build using xCode 8.

Comment: Havent u get this error when buldig and some sytax change issues

Comment: its that when i use legacy settings alamofire get series of changes in source file  plese take a look on example i have given